# How to create and modify stored procedures in EF Core 2.1

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I'm new to using EF and have started with EF Core 2.1.  I have searched for a while but can't seem to find an answer to this question as most results relate to EF6.

I have an existing SQL Server 2016 database with stored procedures and views that I have scaffolded in EF and am now using Code First.

Its working fine however the stored procedures are not in the DbContext created by EF.  I can get rid of most of the stored procedures now EF has taken over but I would like to keep some more complex ones and there are also some in there for reporting.

**What is the best practice for maintenance and creation of stored procedures (and views) here (EF Core 2.1)?**

Should I just continue as I would without EF and create sps directly in the database maybe maintaining a .sql file with changes, or is there a way I can integrate this with EF.
I am not planning on dropping the database anytime as it is loaded with data.

Also new to stackoverflow so if this question deserves a down vote can you give me some feedback on how I can better construct a question next time.

Cheers